# jQuery Datepicker formats date wrong way around

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, haml, date-format

currently all of the dates in my database are formatted like this:

2012-11-06 - so yyyy-mm-dd

but with my new date picker, they are saved like this

2012-06-11 - so yyyy-dd-mm

I need to some how change the way my date picker saves, as when they are converted into proper dates, the new ones are presented like:

2012-06-11 should be 6th November 2012, but instead it comes up as 11th June 2012..

I'm using jQuery, this is how it's installed:

```
%script{:src => "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js", :type => "text/javascript"}
%link{:href => "http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css", :rel => "stylesheet"}/
%script{:src => "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"}
%script{:src => "http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"}
%link{:href => "/resources/demos/style.css", :rel => "stylesheet"}/
:javascript
  $(function() {
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
      $( "#format" ).change(function() {
          $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", $( this ).val() );
      });
  });
```

is there something that I could put in the "dateFormat" bit that could change this??

Update
The column type in the database is "timestamp" could that change anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using this:

```
$("input[name=dateposted]").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
```

Answer (score 2):

From the docs at http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat -

```
dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
```

It is placed as an option to your call to the datepicker:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat:'yyyy-mm-dd'
})
```

Comment: sorry, where do I put this? I literally have no clue what i'm doing with javascript!

Comment: just disables the date picker completely!

Answer (score 0):

Try this    `$.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat = "yy-mm-dd";`

**UPDATE**

```
 $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
      $( "#format" ).change(function() {
            $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat = "yy-mm-dd";
          $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", $( this ).val() );
      });
```

Comment: sorry, where do I put this? I literally have no clue what i'm doing with javascript!

Comment: just disables the date picker completely!